# Why is connection failing when port-forwarding with dynamic dns in same network

Tags: mysql, dns

I have a MySQL database running on my raspberry pi.
To access it I use dynamic DNS (duckdns) when I am outside of my network, but I would like to access it with same dynamic domain name when I am inside my network. However it is not working and I always get connection refused.

I would like somehow enable it so I do not have to change in app.config MySQL server address from my dynamic domain to localhost when I am inside my local network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a gateway router that supports NAT hairpinning.  Many consumer-grade units (and some supposedly commercial-grade equipment) doesn't support this. Either yours doesn't, or you need to find an option to enable it.

When you try to connect to the public IP address from inside the network, the router probably assumes that you want to connect to the router itself.

My cable modem's built-in router at home understands how to do this.  When I access my server from the laptop, and connect to the public IP from inside, the router (inside the cable modem) does a transformation on the packets so that my server sees my connection coming from the router's IP address, not my laptop's IP address.

This is what has to happen, because when the server responds, it will respond to the machine that connected to it.  If it responded to the laptop's address, the laptop would reject the traffic, since it would be coming from ther server's internal IP, which is not the IP address I connected to.  So, it responds to the router, which does a second transform on the packet address, replacing the server's internal IP with the external IP.  Remembering the session from previous traffic, the router then sends the packet back to the laptop.

Ultimately this setup can't possibly work for you without the complicity of your router, which may not have that capability.

Some routers, however, have a DNS proxy that will allow you to create static entries.  My former DSL modem could not hairpin NAT connections, but it had a way to create DNS entries that would be used to respond to internal DNS queries for a specific host... with a different IP than the one that DNS otherwise provided.  That's an alternative workaround if the router supports it.